# How to use a SUM function on a ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, list, object, sum

I have a list of objects (`ObjectX`), and i want to sum the occurences of a specific field (`fieldX`) from this object for each element of the list with the same id (`idX`).

Example folderList:

```
                idX     fieldX      fieldYY
ObjectX1 :      1       50          a
ObjectX2 :      1       null        a
ObjectX3 :      1       30          a
ObjectX4 :      2       99          b
```

I want to get :

```
                idX     fieldX      fieldYY
ObjectX1 :      1       80          a
ObjectX2 :      2       99          b
```

I started by sorting the list to regroup the objects with the same `idX` :
(I'm using Java 1.6)

```
Collections.sort(folderList, new Comparator<ObjectX>()
{
    public int compare(final ObjectX objOne, final ObjectX objTwo)
    {
        Integer orderFirst = objOne.getOrders();
        Integer orderSecond = objTwo.getOrders();
        Integer dareOne = new Integer(0);
        Integer dareTwo = new Integer(0);
        int sComp = orderFirst.compareTo(orderSecond);
        if (sComp != 0) {
            return sComp;
        }
        else {
            dareOne = objOne.getFolderNum();
            dareTwo = objTwo.getFolderNum();
            return dareOne.compareTo(dareTwo);
        }
    }
});
```

But i don't get how i can at the same time sum the `fieldX` values and get only one row by `fieldX` (like the SUM() function in SQL) in a efficient way.

Comment: What happens with `fieldYY`?  Or if `idX` is the same, is `fieldY` also the same?  You may want a `Map` with `idX` as the key.

Comment: fieldYY will always be the same for all the occurences of a given idX.

Answer (score 1):

In java8 you can do like:

```
   Map<Integer,List<ObjectX>> map = folderList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Folder::getId));
```

here key -is id, and value is list of objects with have same id

Comment: Hi said that he used java6. your solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do if you are choose right data structure for your task.

For instance, you have `Map<ObjectX, ObjectXDescription>`
`ObjectXDescription` should encapsulate `idX, fieldX, fieldY`.

Next you can write simple loop which will going through all your entities and sum `fieldX`.

Comment: I was looking to avoid maps, because i need to return a list each time. Converting list to map, then to a list, won't be costly ?

Comment: The conversions will be O(n) each, and will greatly simplify your code.  Sorting takes O(n log n), and you still haven't taken care of summing.  (And don't worry about how long something takes until you've established that it takes a really long time.)

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry This is the right idea, but `ObjectX` encapsulates those fields.  So your map is really a set.  I think you really want a `Map<Integer,ObjectX>` with `idX` as keys.